# How to disable ErrorPageFilter on SpringBoot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to know how to diable ErrorPageFilter.
I am getting this error  :

*15:45:16.380 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR o.s.b.w.s.support.ErrorPageFilter - Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false*

I deploying the application on Tomcat local with eclipse.

My Java classe Application :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "a.b.c.*" })
public class AppWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    public AppWebApplication() {
        super();
        setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SpringApplication.run(AppWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.amm</groupId>
    <artifactId>appweb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>appweb</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>           
        <!-- connexion BDD  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- LOG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I do not know how that mistake was made.

Thank you in advance

Comment: En Anglais s'il vous plait

Comment: Please also edit the title of your question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you need to deactivate `ErrorPageFilter` cause it is really useful.
Do you have changed your dependency to use external tomcat? Is there a reason not to use the embedded tomcat?

You should modify your POM to use an external tomcat.

First, you need to package a WAR application instead of a JAR.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

You have to modify the final WAR file name to avoid including version numbers:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    ... 
</build>
```

Then, we're going to add the Tomcat dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can check this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy it explain better how it works.

*Aller bonne chance et évite le français la prochaine fois :)*

Answer (score 0):

Thomas, thank for help. 
I resolved my problem, I use dispatcherServlet with spring-mvc and missing "/" on the path to access at jsp. 
so generate a ErrorPageFilter exception. 
Add a "/" after "/WEB-INF/jsp" in ViewResolver on dispatcher-servlet.xml resolve execption.

My dispatcher-servlet :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.a.b.controller" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
          <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```